# Why does my Blend have more tris than it says?

Tags: modeling, geometry

My blend has about 552,076 [image]

Tris, however when I press A in object mode, press edit, then check the tris, it's magically 31,083 tris! [image]

I'm not exactly sure why this happens, but it's a huge issue especially since I'm trying to import the whole model into another application. If anyone can help me please let me know!

Comment: to be clear, this is what my mesh looks like:
https://imgur.com/a/yrimTFl

Comment: So you are using subdivision with mirror modifier, suppose your mesh has 100 faces and when you add subdivision modifier then it will increases the faces up to 4 times if level viewport is set to 1 (100*4 = 400) and mirror modifier duplicate the faces in inverse direction so now your mesh has are 800 faces.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but you might have added a **subdivision surface** and forgot to apply it